# less or lesser + assured

Tags: difference, legalese

I already consulted [Is it "less than" or "lesser than"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/820/is-it-less-than-or-lesser-than) (but the answers are contentious) and [Using "lesser" or "smaller" in reference to an abstract quality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4055/8712). [Mod RegDwight's comment under](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/24719):

> Lesser is an adjective. Less is an adverb. Everything else follows.

Source: p 56, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

> In Fitzpatrick
>   v Sterling Housing Association Ltd (1999), the House of Lords had extended the rights
>   of such individuals to inherit the **lesser assured** tenancy by including them within the
>   deceased person’s family. It declined to allow them to inherit statutory tenancies,
>   however, on the grounds that they could not be considered to be the wife or husband of
>   the deceased as the Act required.

**assured** is an adjective. Is this why **lesser** is the only choice? Why not less-assured or less assured?

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24749 says "*Less* refers to quantity, *lesser* refers to quality."
Aren't we concerned with the quantity of the '**assured** tenancy' here? So why not *less*?

Comment: Can you be one assured, two assured or a million assured? Its about quality obviously.

Comment: It is possible that "lesser" is modifying "tenancy" directly.  This might be an example with multiple "assured tenancies", one of which is a "lesser tenancy".  Also, "lesser" sounds like "lessor", which has a completely different meaning.  You might need to find other examples to figure out what word is meant here, let alone what it means.

Answer (score 1):

[lesser](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/lesser) sense 3 (an adverb) and then [less](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/less) sense 5 "to a smaller extent".
Something like:

> That is the lesser of two evils.

So it seems it is a quality measurement. I suppose you could use "less", however "the lesser" is referring to a member of a defined group (using "the").

Legal terminology may have standard ways of saying things, which I would not be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you could indeed replace "lesser" with "less" - but that would change the meaning of the sentence as written.

To paraphrase: the "lesser assured tenancy" can be (and probably should be) read as "the opposite of the *greater* assured tenancy".
If it had been written "less assured tenancy" instead, it would read as "the not-as-certain tenancy", or "the opposite of the more assured tenancy".

The difference between "less" and "lesser" in this context would be something like the following:
A "lesser assured tenancy" is worth less money, and guaranteed ("assured"). 
A "less assured tenancy" is not guaranteed: there's a chance that the tenant might get evicted, or not be allowed to move in.